# Is it possible to import Excel file into OBIEE or OAS and use it with other subject areas?

Tags: excel, oracle, obiee, oracle-analytics

It is known that you could upload an Excel file in Visual Analyzer as a dataset and use that Excel file in Analysis as a separate Subject Area.
However, there was no way (or at least we couldn't find it) to make any connections between this Excel dataset and other subject areas, for example setting connectiong between Excel file's date column with OBIEE's Caledar.Day column, etc.

With new OAS, is there any update on this? Can we somehow make relationships between user-defined datasets and subject areas from rpd? Or is this feature not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you're on OAS you can create data sets which mash up any data source you want. Excel uploaded as a data set can be combined with other uploaded data sets, data sets created by data flows as well as Subject Areas. You have full freedom.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, that was really needed feature for us and if OAS has it, that would solve several problems at once. Haven't moved to OAS yet, since clients are used to OBIEE, but at the end, OAS is inevitable as Oracle would stop support of OBIEE in coming years irrc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe only way to make relationship between data sources is to import them into repository of Analytics.

Maybe if you can import excel as data source into repository, you can manage to relate with other data sources. Here are some links :

https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/obis/obiee_excel_importation

https://www.ascentt.com/importing-excel-file-into-obiee-11g/

I hope these helps.

Hakan

Comment: Thank you, @Hakan, didn't know we could import Excel as a data source directly in admin tool.